# PHP Log Code Not Working

Tags: php, mysqli

I keep getting this error when trying to execute my php code for inserting a log into a logs table in my database:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/thehumanscience/public_html/kyasro1/home.php on line 420

Line 420 is:

```
      $sql = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO logs (username, action, timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?)");
      $sql->bind_param('sss', $usernameLogged, "Updated Contact Info", NOW());

      $sql->execute();
```

Comment: You have three parameters ( ?'s ) in your first statement, and four parameters in your second statement.

Comment: `logs` is keyword https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html and may be the reason why, as it may be interpreted as a function `logs()`. Use ticks around it `\`` and try it again.

Comment: The error means that $sql is not an object. You could var_dump it to get more info, but it's probably FALSE meaning that mysqli->prepare() returned an error.

Comment: @P.Gearman That's correct; the first parameter defines the types of the remaining parameters.

Comment: we also need to know which MySQL API you're using here. `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO? other? those different APIs do not intermix and make sure those variables are correct, and that you chose the right database/table etc. checking for errors on your execute will tell you that and you're not checking for errors. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object on line 420

Comment: Ah, my bad. Mea culpa.

Although now that I look at the function reference, can I say that I'm surprised that there's not a parameter type for datetime?

Comment: replace `$sql->execute();` with `if(!$sql->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` then comes back and tell us what the *real* error is, including error reporting. These comments are getting too long here. and go over ALL of MY comments again. anyone using my comments as an answer, will NOT have my blessing.

Comment: Whats the down vote for?

Comment: plus, `action` and `timestamp` are also keywords https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html and you should try and stay away from using those as they may have adverse effects. I said "keywords" here folks, not "reserved" words. 2 different animals.

Comment: I just updated my original post. Error reporting IS on and not throwing anything. Give me a break here guys...I'm seeking a little assistance here and providing what I have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102510/discussion-between-chuck-robertson-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind `NOW()` as you have tried to do. If you want to use MySQL functions you have to use them "right out of the box" so to speak:

```
$sql = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `logs` (`username`, `action`, `timestamp`) VALUES (?,?,NOW())");
$sql->bind_param('ss', $usernameLogged, "Updated Contact Info");
```

Make sure that the column type for `timestamp` is correct. If you'd rather, you could get a timestamp from PHP for the third variable and bind to that instead.

---

Note that I have back ticked the table and column names. As my good friend Fred -ii pointed out, they are [keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) (not reserved) and the back ticking *is not required* for keywords. I just find it to be good practice.

---

Based on a discussion with the OP and my still good friend Fred -ii the following changes needed to be made:

You cannot embed a string directly in the `bind_param()` statement. Assigning the string to a variable as well as moving the NOW() function took care of the issues:

```
$actionTaken = "Updated Contact Info";
$sql = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `logs` (`username`, `action`, `timestamp`) VALUES (?,?,NOW())"); 
$sql->bind_param('ss', $usernameLogged, $actionTaken);
```

Comment: Would we not have to add the timestamp parameters to the bind_param statement? Tried this and still get: 

Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 3 by reference on line 387

Comment: You shouldn't have to. Are you positive `$usernameLogged` is populated? Make sure you use the second line of code I've posted here as I am only binding two parameters.

Comment: Yes. I'm able to echo out the username just fine:

Comment: *"and my still good friend Fred -ii"* - bin oui mon cher ami ;-) toujours

Comment: *Ah..., a green tick Sam!!* - @JayBlanchard *Yessss!!*

Comment: Thanks so much to Jay and Fred -ii! Super helpful and gracious!

Comment: Any time @ChuckRobertson! Glad we were able to get it sorted out.

Comment: @ChuckRobertson You're most welcome Chuck, glad we were able to help out and find a 100% solution, *cheers!*

Comment: *One for the history books Sam* - @JayBlanchard *Good thing for chat mode* ;-) ciao mon ami. *Bookmarking this one*.

Comment: *Sure was Sam!* - @JayBlanchard *I always loved a happy ending myself*